# Matbadge Count is not updating after Crud operation

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs-observables

I would really appreciate help here i am not sure how to solve this issue.

I have Following Code For Changing Read status of messages.
but when i change status from message component the count that i use in navbar is not updating same goes for Delete function also.

i am Calling this updateStatus method on Button Click. it will update read Booleanfield in database.
messageComponent.ts

```
 updateStatus(messageId, readStatus){
    this.service.update(messageId, readStatus).subscribe(res=> {
      let updateStatus = this.messages.find(m => m.uid == res.data.uid);
      let index = this.messages.indexOf(updateStatus);
      this.messages[index].read = readStatus;
    });
  }
```

messageService.ts

```
  getAllMessages() {
     const options = {url : url, headers: headers}
     const response = Http.request({...options, method: GET})
     return from(response).pipe(shareReplay(1))
  }

 updateMessage(messageId, readStatus){
    const options = {url : url, headers: headers, , data: {read: readStatus}}
    const response = Http.request({...options, method: PATCH})
    return from(response).pipe(shareReplay(1))
 }
```

I send messagecounter as Input for menuitem component. as i have build custom scrollable navigationbar so i need to separate all part of navbar in different component.

navBarComponent.ts

```
    constructor(private messageService:MessageService) {
        this.messageService.getAllMessages().subscribe(message => {
            this.messageCounter = message.data.results.filter(msg => msg.read === false).length;
          });      
    }
```

navbarComponet.html

```
 <ul>
<li style="width: 100%;">
            <app-navigation-menu-item [icon]="icons.notification" [url]="'/messages'" [countBadge]="messageCounter">
            </app-navigation-menu-item>
        </li>
</ul>
```

NavigationMenuitem.html

```
<span  matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgeSize="small" matBadgePosition="above before"
   [matBadge]="countBadge"  [matBadgeHidden]="countBadge ==''"></span>
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Well, you are only setting `this.messageCounter` once in your constructor. Where exactly do you expect this value to change? It is also a little bit that you are using `return from(response).pipe(shareReplay(1))` in your service, which will create a new observable each time the function is called. So it does not really make sense to even use `shareReplay` to share the initial observable amongst multiple subscribers.

Comment: i wan to change the value on Mat-badge when status in message component changes.and for response i have removed shareReplay but do you suggest any better way to handle the response?

Comment: I assume your question is basically: Why does my subscription to `this.messageService.getAllMessages()` is only called once and not each time I update something, is that correct?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should know why your approach does not work:
In your `navBarComponent` you are subscribing to `this.messageService.getAllMessages()`, which will be called exactly one time. This is an HTTP request, which is happening independently from other HTTP calls. If some other component is calling `updateMessage` this has nothing to do with the initial subscription from `navBarComponent`.

Suggestion: You should move your `this.messages` object to your service should define it as an BehaviorSubject (which will initially get the value of `getAllMessages()`. Each time you call your `update` function you should also 'next' the values to your subject. Now you can subscribe in both components to this subject and derive your actual state in whatever logic you want to have.
If you provide a Stackblitz example, I can also fork the repo and adjust the code accordingly (if needed).

Note: Is there a particular reason you seem to not be using Angular HTTP Client? You wouldn't have to transform a promise to an observable this way, since it is returning an observable right away.

Comment: Hey @Fabian Strathaus i have Found one problem with the solution. 
behaviour subject removes the data on reload. 
i have to call getAllmessage api on everypage to set the intial value as counter is in navbar i am using it in all the pages.

Comment: You mean data gets removed as soon as you reload your browser window? This is intended behavior. If you want to keep the data you have to use sessionStorage or localStorage. If data is lost on navigating to a different route (using Angular Router), this is not intended behavior. BehaviorSubject should still hold the last value and emit it to new subscribers.